# Trigger Cloudwatch Alarm + when message successfully processed in @SQSListener + Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I have one SQS queue and one listener method running in the task of ECS Fargate service. What I needed is when one message processed successfully, I want to trigger cloud watch alarm ? I could not be able to find any SQS metric for that.

```
@SqsListener(value = "StageQueue",deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void listen(String message) {
    log.info("!!!! received message {} {}", message.toString());
    String message = doSomeProcessing();
    // I want to trigger cloudwatch alarm here, that this message processed successfully
}
```

Comment: What is the alarm supposed to do?  If you just need it to trigger an SNS action notifying that the message has been successfully processed, I'd say directly trigger the SNS action in your code.

Comment: Actually i need to stop the task on which this listener is running. What should i do?